# How to filter mapbox fetaure using radius and latlng

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a layer on mapbox studio containing all the postal code plotted on the map and I am accessing it using access key and layer id ,

I want to filter out only the postal code (marker)   inside a  radius

Answer (score 0):

Turf provides a [pointsWithinPolygon()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon) function, that helps you to find any points within the circle. Here is an example:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGFybmRlcHUiLCJhIjoiY2l6dXZ5OXVkMDByZDMycXI2NGgyOGdyNiJ9.jyTchGQ8N1gjPdra98qRYg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-46.6062, -23.5513],
  zoom: 11
});

map.on('load', function () {

  // List of your marker locations
  var points = turf.points([
      [-46.6318, -23.5523],
      [-46.6246, -23.5325],
      [-46.6062, -23.5513],
      [-46.663, -23.554],
      [-46.643, -23.557]
  ]);

  // Create circle with radius
  var center = [-46.6062, -23.5513];
  var radius = 3;
  var options = {steps: 10, units: 'kilometers', properties: {foo: 'bar'}};
  var circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);

  // Find point within circle
  var markerWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, circle);

  console.log("Found: " + markerWithin.features.length + " points");
  
  // Draw circle polygon
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'circle',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': circle
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#525252',
      'fill-opacity': 0.2
    }
  });
  
  // Draw all points 
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'points',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': points
    },
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': 5,
      'circle-color': 'red',
      'circle-opacity': 1
    }
  });
  
  // Draw marker with in circle
  markerWithin.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // Create marker
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
  });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; };
```

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: I would suggest not to disable it but remove it instead. Use `map.removeLayer('points');` where "points" is the layer ID.

Comment: Actually, I have all the postal code plotted on the map hidden, I want only that postal code which fall in the circle to be visible ,

Comment: Follow this link: https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon, you will get some ideas.